# Is there any way I can retrieve the console output for a particular step of a particular stage in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using groovy to author a Jenkins pipeline script. I want to retrieve the console output of a particular step of a particular stage so that I can process that data and send a part of it in an email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BlueOcean REST API for that:

```
pipeline {

    agent { node { label "master" } }

    stages {
        stage('A') { steps { script {
                    println "All good"
        }}}
        stage('B') { steps { script {
                    println "Everything's peaches"
        }}}
        stage('C') { steps { script {
                    println "Something happened"
                    sh "false"
        }}}
    }

    post { 
        failure {
            script {
                processFailure()
            }
        }
    }
}


def processFailure() {
    def value = env.BUILD_URL
    def myre = ~/^${JENKINS_URL}job\/(?<urlproj>[\S]+)\/(?<urlbuild>[\S]+)\//

    def matcher = value =~ myre
    if (matcher.matches()) {  
        def urlproj = matcher.group('urlproj')
        def urlbuild  = matcher.group('urlbuild')
        matcher = null
        processLog (urlproj, urlbuild)
    }
}

def processLog (String urlproj,  String urlbuild) {
    def nodes_url = JENKINS_URL + "/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/${urlproj}/runs/${urlbuild}/nodes/"
    println nodes_url

    def output = sh (returnStdout: true,
        script: "curl -s '${nodes_url}'")
    def parsed_data = readJSON text: output
    
    def found_the_problem = false
    
    for (stage in parsed_data) {
        if (found_the_problem) { 
            break 
        }

        if (stage.result == 'FAILURE') {
            println "stage.displayName: ${stage.displayName} FAILURE"
            
            steps_url = JENKINS_URL + stage._links.steps.href
            output = sh (returnStdout: true,
                script: "curl -s ${steps_url}")
            parsed_steps_data = readJSON text: output
            for (step in parsed_steps_data) {
                if (found_the_problem) { 
                    break 
                }
                
                if (step.result != 'SUCCESS') {
                    println "${step.displayName} step.result: ${step.result}"
                    
                    def actions = step.actions
                    for (action in actions) {
                        if (found_the_problem) { 
                            break 
                        }
                        
                        if (action.urlName == 'log') {
                            def log_url = JENKINS_URL + action._links.self.href
                            def log_text = sh (returnStdout: true,
                                script: "curl -s ${log_url}")
                            println "HERE IS THE LOG:" 
                            println log_text
                            found_the_problem = true
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
https://jenkins....//blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/3301/nodes/
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -s https://jenkins....//blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/3301/nodes/
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
stage.displayName: C FAILURE
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -s https://jenkins...../blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/3301/nodes/24/steps/
[Pipeline] readJSON
[Pipeline] echo
Shell Script step.result: FAILURE
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -s https://jenkins.....//blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/test/runs/3301/nodes/24/steps/28/log/
[Pipeline] echo
HERE IS THE LOG:
[Pipeline] echo
+ false
script returned exit code 1

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try that @MaratC